is `uintXX_t` guaranteed to be the unsigned type of `intXX_t`
is it a guaranteed by the standard that this is true?
Like if for example I am using windows, int and long have same size will it be guaranteed that if int32_t is for example an alias to a signed int it is guaranteed that uint32_t is an alias to unsigned int and not unsigned long.
I need this to avoid UB while type aliasing.

The standard only says that it must provide these typedefs if there are integer types of the proper size. But any compiler that mixes long with unsigned int would not be all that popular. Zero users, I would guess!

static_assert(typeid(int) == typeid(std::int32_t));

@Eljay you seem to not understand my question reread it again

@Eljay also the correct way to test is this static_assert<std::is_same_v<std::make_signed_t<uintXX_t>,intXX_t>

@user - Perhaps you should ask about your intended type aliasing instead? That sounds seriously dangerous! And close to being an XY problem

Also, unlike the old C typedefs, std::make_signed is specified to provide "the corresponding type". Not just a type with the same number of bits.

@BoP I have a socket I have overloads for every fized integer type but it is having alot of duplicates and I wanted to implement the signed ones interms of the unsigned one by a reinterpret_cast which is safe to use to convert from signed T to unsigned T this does not affect the bit partern which is importsnt

I don't think the standard says anything about this issue. Every implementation I've seen has the property you are looking for, and I don't see why anyone would ever do it differently, but there's no guarantee by the standard. That said, using std::make_signed / std::make_unsigned as others have suggested avoids this entire mess if you just want to perform a reinterpret_cast, and they work well even with templated types.

uintXX_t should always be the unsigned version of intXX_t, with the same number bits (XX bits). Please explain what is the actual problem you are trying to solve, where what I wrote in the first sentence is not good enough.

@wohlstad where is your proof and read my comment

std::bit_cast should help in the case they are different "base" ints, shouldn't they?

@user24551355 all the relevant info should be in your question. But anyway I cannot cite the standard on this, I just know that's the situation in just about any implementation out there (and I am familiar with quite a few).  I am aware this is a language-lawyer question, which is why I wrote a comment, not an answer.

@Raildex I am writing this for C++13 I can use memcpy though

@user24551355 fixed-width integers are only part of the C++11 standard onwards

@wohlstad what is missing in my question? the socket part is not necessary for the question I am asking for something then others should answer it

@user24551355 I agree your question is valid as is. Nevertheless adding some context could help understand the issue. In any case I see that you got an answer. I think it is a good one.

[cstdint.syn]p2:

The header defines all types and macros the same as the C standard library header <stdint.h>.
See also: ISO/IEC 9899:2018, 7.20

ISO/IEC 9899:2018 §7.20.1p1

When typedef names differing only in the absence or presence of the initial u are defined, they shall denote corresponding signed and unsigned types as described in 6.2.5; an implementation providing one of these corresponding types shall also provide the other.

It does not take too much more reading of the standards to guarantee that for all N, static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::intN_t, std::make_signed_t<std::uintN_t>>); will succeed if std::intN_t is defined.
